# Convert Compass to Bourbon

Tags: sass

I would love to be able to convert magento's compass to using bourbon.  so that i can use libsass to do faster scss compile.  Also I just like bourbon better.

How can this be accomplished?

I was taking a look at this to help me https://moovwebconfluence.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TS/Converting+Compass+based+projects+to+LibSass+and+Spracker

Comment: I was looking at converting to Less because that's what Magento2 uses, but it's clear libsass+bourbon would be so much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Compass and Bourbon are pretty different, Compass includes it's own Ruby functions which (in their words) are magic. Bourbon is just a SCSS library so it won't have this functionality.

I think you'd need to go through each Compass function/mixin and convert it to the Bourbon equivilent, if you're using any of the 'magic' ruby functions such as sprite generation you'll also need to implement a Gulp/Grunt/NPM setup to do this for you.